# \blacktriangle not showing if unicode-math included

Tags: unicode-math, amssymb

Following example shows only the square and lozenge (XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998) the other three symbols being shown as spaces whereas if unicode-math is removed, the symbols are shown correctly. Is there a way to show the symbols correctly whilst using unicode-math?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$$a\blacksquare \blacklozenge \blacktriangle \blacktriangledown \bigstar b$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't mix `amssymb` with `unicode-math`.

You can supply the missing glyphs from another math font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range={\mdlgblklozenge,\mdblksquare,\blacktriangle,\blacktriangledown,\bigstar}
]

\providecommand{\blacksquare}{\mdblksquare}
\providecommand{\blacklozenge}{\mdlgblklozenge}

\begin{document}

\[
a\blacksquare \blacklozenge \blacktriangle \blacktriangledown \bigstar b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are smaller variants; it makes sense to load also them and then decide about the size at the end.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range={
    \mdlgblklozenge,
    \smblklozenge,
    \mdblksquare,
    \smblksquare,
    \blacktriangle,
    \blacktriangledown,
    \bigstar,
  },
]

\providecommand{\blacksquare}{\smblksquare}
\providecommand{\blacklozenge}{\smblklozenge}

\begin{document}

\[
a\blacksquare \blacklozenge \blacktriangle \blacktriangledown \bigstar b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You're not tied to using math fonts for specific symbols. For instance, you might resort to a standard font supplying them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newfontface{\altfont}{FreeSerif}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand{\blacksquare}{\text{\altfont\symbol{"25A0}}}%
  \providecommand{\blacklozenge}{\text{\altfont\symbol{"29EB}}}%
  \renewcommand{\blacktriangle}{\text{\altfont\symbol{"25B2}}}%
  \renewcommand{\blacktriangledown}{\text{\altfont\symbol{"25BC}}}%
  \renewcommand{\bigstar}{\text{\altfont\symbol{"2605}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
a\blacksquare \blacklozenge \blacktriangle \blacktriangledown \bigstar b
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The log shows

```
Missing character: There is no ▴ in font [latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;
language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ▾ in font [latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;
language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ★ in font [latinmodern-math.otf]/OT:script=math;
language=DFLT;!
```

so the font doesn't contain these characters. You could try a different main font, or define these to come from the ams fonts

For example I get

[image]

if I add

```
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
```

Comment: I tried but couldn't find the right result. +1. I have tried with `\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}`

Comment: @Sebastiano the tex gyre fonts come from the same team as the OTF latin modern and have similar character set. stix is more complete.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Give `XITS Math` and `Stix Two Math` a try.