# \blacktriangle and \blacktriangledown on beamer slides

Tags: beamer, symbols

I used for my thesis the `\blacktriangle` and `\blacktriangledown` commands and they work. I used the `book` document class.

Instead now I need to replicate them on a presentation, using the `beamer` document class. However in such a case the symbols do not appear and no related error seems to occur within the log.

EDIT: the symbol goes in conflict with the package `unicode-math`. However, when removing this package my colored bullets in math mode stop working: `$\textcolor{green}{\textbullet}$`.

EDIT 2: solved by using `\bullet` instead of `\textbullet`.

Comment: Seems to work fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB5Y0.png Can you please add a short, but compilable test document which allows us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I tried with `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Triangles}
Triangles: $\blacktriangledown \blacktriangle$
\end{frame}
\end{document}` and that works ok. Could you check if this document works for you as well?

Comment: I am trying to create a short test, but nothing, it works! Even by using all the packages of my presentation. I don't know what to look at.

Comment: @DanieleCuomo Make a copy of the problematic document, then remove things as long as you can still reproduce the problem.

Comment: These two symbols are defined in the package `amssymb`.  I'm not sure that this package is always loaded in `beamer`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton By default, beamer loads it (unless the OP uses any special options, but we would need to see a mwe)

Comment: I am tryng by removing piece by piece, but it keeps working. I'll update as soon as I find a mwe.

Comment: Duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483631/blacktriangle-not-showing-if-unicode-math-included